# Multiple SalesForce instances with a single ExactTarget Enterprise 2.0

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is it possible to have multiple instances of SalesForce setup with a single instance of an ExactTarget Enterprise 2.0?

For instance, different SalesForce instances being used in different business units in the NAB Enterprise?

Answer (score 1):

An Enterprise 2.0 Account can only be integrated with one Salesforce Instance.  The integration would be setup under the Parent Account and each BU below it, would inherit the integration settings from the Parent.

See below link for details on the newest version (V5) of the Integration:

[SFV5 Prerequisites and Critical Concepts](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_salesforce_integration_v5/salesforce_v5_install_guide/prerequisites_and_critical_concepts/)

Answer (score 0):

An Enterprise 2.0 Account can be integrated with multiple Salesforce Instance.  The integration would be setup under each BU

See below link for details on the newest version (V5) of the Integration:

[SFV5 Prerequisites and Critical Concepts](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_salesforce_integration_v5/salesforce_v5_install_guide/prerequisites_and_critical_concepts/)

You will also need to ensure you upgrade your E2 account to MultiOrg

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/features/multi_org_account_configuration/upgrading_to_multi_org/

Answer (score -2):

It is recommended that we should use exacttarget in separate browsers.
There are synchronization issues if we open multiple windows in the same browsers.